# jQuery $.Deferreds and $.each

Tags: jquery, each, jquery-deferred

Attempting to use $.Deferreds in place of setTimeOut which I was using prior.
I'm running into an issue, as writer() isn't actually done, because the $.each are still looping at the time printer() is called.

I haven't seen an example of $.Deferreds with loops. Obviously the below is wrong, and I'm betting it has to do with the resolve - any help would be appreciated.

```
$.when( writer() ).done(function() {
    printer();
});


function writer(){
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    if(x){
        $("a").each(function () {...});
    }
    if(y){
        $("img").each(function () {...});
    }
    if(z){
        $("div").each(function () {...});
    }
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise();

}

function printer(){...}
```

Comment: Think about it, you are ALWAYS resolving it before you return it, so the `.done` will always happen immediately after calling `writer`, regardless of whether or not whatever asynchronous events inside of your `.each` are done. If you aren't doing any asynchronous work inside the `$.each`, you don't need deferred objects.

Comment: @KevinB - that's exactly what I figured was happening, just not sure how to return multiple deferreds before triggering printer()

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you calling `.each()` on a jQuery object that will only ever contain at most one element?

Comment: I would have to know what the asynchronous event is, `$.each` is synchronous meaning `printer` can't run until all of the `$.each` are done.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - dummied it for the code, bad example - will edit.

Comment: Looks like it might be straightforward synchronous code, in which case Deferred(s) are not required. If I'm wrong and the asynchronicity is AJAX-induced, then you should build one (large) AJAX request and respond to its response with one simple `jqXHR.done(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `...` inside of the `.each` is doing an asynchronous event, you'll need all of those asynchronous events to return a deferred object that you can pass into a `$.when` to trigger your resolve.

Also, at the top of your code, you don't need `$.when` for a single callback, just do `writer().done(function(){...})`

Comment: see updated - $.each is wrapped in an if - so how to return the deferred in the $.each and ensure all are returned that are true?